# C++ OrientDB driver by tglman

Tags: c++, database-connection, orientdb

Unable to connect to the database using the sample program provided. I'm getting an error at this line

```
o_database_document_open(db, "root", "password");
```

Anyone who succeeded with db connection? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the link to the sample program
https://github.com/tglman/orientdb-c/wiki/Start

Comment: show us your db object ;)

Comment: It is the same code as provided in the link.

Comment: That code is from 24 Feb 2012... way too old. You should ask for a update on that code there.